# Xcode: UIButton setImage does not change the image of the button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, tvos

**NOTE:** Others have asked a similar question and none of the answers provided solved my problem.

Here's my code:

```
   @IBOutlet var testButton:UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       self.testButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icn_checkbox_")?.imageWithColor(color: CMStyle.darkBlueColor), for: .normal)
        self.testButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icn_checked")?.imageWithColor(color: CMStyle.darkBlueColor), for: .selected)
        
    }
 @IBAction func testButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        print("INSIDE testButtonAction")
              self.testButton.isSelected = !self.testButton.isSelected
              print("self.testButton.isSelected: ",self.testButton.isSelected)
    }
```

This is the button:
[image].
These are the characteristics of the button:
[image].
This is **icn_checkbox_** image used for `.normal` state:
[image]
This is **icn_checked** image used for `.selected` state:
[image]

The code inside `testButtonAction` gets executed. So I don't really see why wouldn't the image change (Why doesn't the button become checked).

Comment: No, it's logged as an Optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
@IBOutlet var testButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
       self.testButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icn_checkbox_")?.imageWithColor(color: CMStyle.darkBlueColor), for: .normal)
}

@IBAction func testButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
       print("INSIDE testButtonAction")
       self.testButton.isSelected = !self.testButton.isSelected
       if self.testButton.isSelected {
          self.testButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icn_checked")?.imageWithColor(color: CMStyle.darkBlueColor), for: .normal)
       } else {
          self.testButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icn_checkbox_")?.imageWithColor(color: CMStyle.darkBlueColor), for: .normal)
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set images for button states just in Storyboard, where Default = .normal and Selected = .selected

[image]

Choose selected and set image there. Image with color is similar to tintColor if You're using template images